# What does bind(this) in constructor do in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am familiar with Javascript function *bind*. But I don't understand why in following React.js snippet is *this* bind again to *this*. Has is something common with *constructor*, because *this* in constructor can have different values depending on usage?

Thank you in advance for replies

```js
class QuotesLibrary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.search = debounce(this.search.bind(this), 300);
  }
  search(searchTerm) {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({searchTerm});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="quotes-library">
        <SearchForm searchAction={this.search} />
        <div className="quotes-list">
          {this.props.library.quotesConnection.edges.map(edge =>
            <Quote key={edge.node.id} quote={edge.node} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `this.search.bind(this)` does it that it is binding the key `this` inside to the function to the context of your React Component and what it basically means is that whenever you try to access a property of the `React Component`, you can access it like `this.props` since `this` will then refer to the React Component's context and not the function itself.

The significance of `this.search` before `bind` is that it is trying to access the function `search` which is in the `context` of the `React Component` and hence you are only binding it once and not twice.

I hope I was able to explain the situation properly

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use Function.bind(this) : you should use arrow function. Arrow functions are bind to the class (so to the component).

```
class QuotesLibrary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.search = debounce(this.search, 300);
  }

  search = (searchTerm) => {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({searchTerm});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="quotes-library">
        <SearchForm searchAction={this.search} />
        <div className="quotes-list">
          {this.props.library.quotesConnection.edges.map(edge =>
            <Quote key={edge.node.id} quote={edge.node} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how the difference works -

As you can see, the first call will log 'undefined' and the second one will log 'Bar', because the 1st call wasn't binded, and calling functions indirectly (as promise results or as callbacks) doesn't keep the reference to `this` when it runs - bind tells it what its `this` is referring to.

```js
function debounce(fn, to) {
    setTimeout(fn)
}

class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.fullName = 'Bar'
  }
  
  speak () {
    console.log("My name is", this.fullName)
  }
  
  test () {
    debounce(this.speak, 1000) // undefined
    debounce(this.speak.bind(this), 2000) // "Bar"
    
  }
}

let foo = new Foo()

foo.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saying "again"? You only bind it once, not twice.

debounce from _underscores library takes a function and returns another, therefore to get the `this` context in the search function you need to bind it to the `search`.

It's the exact same as binding functions normally in the constructor.